# SQL Server Link Database to Excel File not showing any tables but with no errors

Tags: sql-server, windows

I am using SQL Server 2017 on Windows 2022 and am creating a linked server to an excel table to import data.

I have ensured that I have installed the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver:

[image]

I have used the following script to add the linked server:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
     @server = N'test1',
     @srvproduct = N'Excel',
     @provider = N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
     @datasrc = N'C:\mytest\testexcel.xlsx',
     @provstr = N'Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;';
```

I run the script: no errors.
I right click on the newly created linked server and test the connection: It connects OK

[image]

However, there is no Sheet1$ as expected.

I am left scratching my head as I am not getting any errors.

Comment: If it were showing default worksheets in a document you would expect to see `Sheet1$` as opposed to `$sheet1`. Does the document actually have any worksheets - with data in them - or have they all been deleted?

Comment: Please edit your question, and add T-SQL to show how you are querying a MS Excel file.

Comment: I can't show you how I am querying a file that does not exist. I am unable to get to the point of querying data that wasn't showing. Please read the question as your comment is outside the scope of the question and you have clearly not understood what I am asking.

Comment: No need to be snarky, i think what Yitzhak ment was usually to get excel data, you do a SELECT * FROM test1...Sheet1$ and not use the clunky ssms gui to browse stuff, does the selecting work badly as well without this provider setting

Comment: I'm not 'being snarky' just trying to work out why the table isn't showing in the gui as expected so that I can move on to using it for SELECT's. I certainly wouldn't continue to use a table unless it was displaying properly in case there was another issue.

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue:

Although having setup many instances of SQL server and installed the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver many times I do not recall having to modify the properties of the driver to allow it to work.

I am not sure if the defaults have changed but by investigations led me to an old server to compare the driver settings and I found that on our old server the "Allow inprocess" driver option was checked.

I went to our new server and found it was not checked, so did the following:

Right clicked on the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver

[image]

Then ensure the Allow inprocess is checked.

[image]

This seems to have cured the issue.

However, I did some searches for the usage of the Allow inprocess setting but can find no documentation, so even though it works, I don't know why.